# Swift- How to add onto arraylist next index everytime save button is pressed

Tags: arrays, swift, arraylist, uitextfield

Hi my question is how can I store a string value which contails all textfield input into an array with new index every time I press save. I have created some code below however I think its overriding the first index.

```
@IBAction func Save (_ sender: UIButton){
let firstextfield = textfield1.text
let secondtextfield = textfield2.text

let allText = firsttextfield! + "," + secondtextfield!
var myArray = [String]()
var index : Int = 0

while (myArray.count) <= index {
   myArray.insert(allText, at: index)

}
index +=


for element in myArray{
 print(element)
 }


}
```

input: firsttextfield = 9.22 and secondtextfield = 91.2
save button is then pressed.

output:

```
Optional ("9.22,91.2")
Optional ("")
```

if i were to then change the values of my textfields to firsttextfield = 0.2 and secondtextfield = 20.2

I get output :

```
Optional ("0.2,20.2")
Optional ("")
```

I dont want it to overide the array but to add onto it so expected output:

```
Optional ("9.22,91.2")
Optional ("0.2,20.2")
```

Any tips are welcome as I am new to coding.

Comment: i think  you can append value into array right?

Comment: @Jaydip it appeds an empty string value but i want it to append a new string in the next index instead of overriding the current 1

Comment: but why append empty?

Comment: @Jaydip ah thats a mistake it was suppose to append allText

Comment: ohhk bro I understand and i got your issue,

Comment: Just declare your index variable outside of your button action

Comment: @Jaydip ive place insert method shown y Yashi into my while loop however how can i increment index value properly so that everytime button is pressed it increments by 1. At the moment my increment stays at 0 therefore overriding value in index 0. I have also changed the code to show what I done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167092/discussion-between-jaydip-and-user7388968).

Comment: just check my answere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Just Declare outside of button action

```
var index = 0
var myArray = [String?]()
```

//Button action

```
@IBAction func btnShareTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let firstextfield = "textfield1.text"
    let secondtextfield = "textfield2.text"

    let allText = firstextfield + "," + secondtextfield

    while (myArray.count) <= index {
        myArray.append("")
    }

    myArray.insert(allText, at: index)
    index = index + 1

    for element in myArray{
        print(element)
    }
    print(myArray)
}
```

**Output**

```
[Optional("textfield1.text,textfield2.text"), Optional("")]
[Optional("textfield1.text,textfield2.text"), Optional("textfield1.text,textfield2.text"), Optional("")]
```

//your last comment answer is

```
let a : String = myArray[0]!
let b = a.split(separator: ",")
label.text = b[0] as! String
label1.text = b[1] as! String
```

Comment: would it still work if i replaced myArray.append("") to myArray.insert(allText, at : index) or do i have to have a append before i can use insert?

Comment: if you delete append code still it's working properly, and i still don't understand why you are write apped code because do not any need for yet

Comment: I just replaced the append with the insert line and it works perfectly ty.

Comment: also if i were to send this array to another viewController how would i iterate through each index putting the values for firsttextfield and secondtextfield into automatically created labels

Comment: i think your idea is good but your way of writing code is wrong, it's make all thing simple using arrayOfDictionary it's very easy.

Comment: Just Check my updated answere, i wirte iterate value code

Answer (score 1):

I think your emptying the array here:

```
var myArray = [String?]()
var index = 0

while (myArray.count) <= index {
myArray.append("")

}
```

declare and initialise it outside the function and then use this to insert values to array:

```
let allText = firsttextfield! + "," + secondtextfield!

anArray.append(allText)
```

Comment: hi I have placed the line to insert inside my while statement however how can if fix it so that index increments by 1 everytime button is pressed. At the moment it keeps overriding the current inside index 0 which shows tat the index is not being incremented.. How can I fix this so once save is pressed for the second time it adds the new data to 1

Comment: see my edited answer, you don't need to increment index.

Comment: `.append()` always places the value at the end of array. whereas `.insert()` places it at the given position within the array.